# How to use tasks in discord.py?

Tags: python, datetime, discord, task, discord.py

I want the bot to run a function at a specified time. After trying 100's of different things , I wrote this:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def checkTime():

    now = datetime.now()

    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("Current Time =", current_time)

    if current_time == '16:41:00':  
        channel = bot.get_channel(746339276983238677)
        await channel.send("It's time.")
        print('its time')
checkTime.start()
```

it prints `current_time` in console after every 5 seconds but it doesn't send any message to the channel and also doesn't print `it's time` in console at the time specified. It doesn't throw any error so I don't know whats wrong.
please do answer if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` returns you `datetime` type, not `str`. So you can't compare `datetime` with `str`. You have to convert `datetime` to `str`.

So if you do `current_time = str(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))` or `if str(current_time) == '16:41:00':`, it will be work.

**EDIT**

For getting the day's name, you can use `%A`, for example:

```py
today = datetime.datetime.now()
day_name = today.strftime('%A')
if day_name == 'Sunday':
    #do whatever you want
```

Comment: I figured out what was missing , I just had to put `await bot.wait_until_ready()` on the top of loop. Still I want to know is there a way I can skip it if the day is sunday?